# Django unquote() with url parameters

Tags: django, django-urls, django-request

I had used unquote in my urls before to get special characters in the url like so:

```
path('example/<str:phone_number>', views.find_user_by_phone_number.as_view(), name='api.find_user_by_phone_number'),
#call with example/+849323212231
```

and in my views:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

.....

   phone_number = unquote(phone_number)
   print(phone_number)
```

It worked great and i got `+849323212231` with special character `+`

But now i need to make url with multiple parameters that can has `phone_number` in it:

```
path('example', views.find_user_by_phone_number.as_view(), name='api.find_user_by_phone_number'),
    #call with example?phone_number=+849323212231
```

With view to handle parameter:

```
...
  phone_number = unquote(request.GET.get('phone_number'))
  print(phone_number)
```

And the result from the print i got was " 849323212231" with whitespace at the start.

Seems like value from `request.GET.get('phone_number')` return " 849323212231" so plus turned into whitespace.

Expected to get `+849323212231` from `request.GET.get('phone_number')`

How do i get special character with named parameter in url ?

Comment: have you tried `urlunquote_plus`

Comment: @Exprator yes i had tried with `phone_number = unquote_plus(request.GET.get('phone_number'))` it still return " 849323212231" without plus

Comment: hmm the problem is, u r escaping it while taking the phone number only, use the whole url like `unqoute(url)` then get the `phone_number`

Comment: `request.get_full_path()` return `/example?phone_number= 849323212231 ` so i guess i can't even get it from the full url path

Comment: plus sign is a reserved character, can you show how you are submitting those values? form or ajax? add the code here.

Comment: i don't use the form, i just call the GET api from postman. As the code my get request in django only has that for now, the request.GET worked for other parameters , just having difficulty with special characters in parameter value